# PWA autorization storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I'm building a PWA. Partial functionality will be available to all users, but full functionality will be available only to users that paid for the product. I'm using IndexedDB for storage and React as frontend library. My question is: How or where would I save boolean value hasPaid: true, on which functionality would be presented? (And avoid user changing this value to grant himself full app functionality.). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Somewhere in the backend, tied to your users id. You might as well consider using two frontends, one for paid users that includes additional features and one for free users that doesn't ship the code for the paid version.

Comment: It should be fully offline, so after install (and payment) no internet is needed... Backend is not an option. Any sugestions?

Comment: You're going to need to store what is essentially a license key on the front end which can be verified by a one-way function in the app to determine whether said license is legitimate or not. Said one way function will probably have to run inside a Webworker or WASM module, else someone can just reverse engineer it. Not gunna be easy, and also not something someone will be able to answer here in a single question.

Comment: @apple314 That's not possible. Any client-side only code can be reverse engineered and exploited.

Comment: @apple314 What you could do is using something like AWS Lambda / Google Cloud functions to provide a serverless way of verifying license keys. It's still a backend, but you won't have to have a server running all the time.

Comment: @jmkmay  Thank you very much for the idea and pointing me in the right direction.